# Timezone changes not applying in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, timezone

I have changed my timezone in CentOS6 with below command

```
[root@localhost puppetserver]# ls -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta /etc/localtime
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta  /etc/localtime
[root@localhost puppetserver]# date
Mon Jan 30 22:38:49 EST 2017
```

I even tried after sometime but still changes are not reflected.

## EDIT

output of `env | sort`

```
[root@localhost puppetserver]# env | sort
_=/bin/env
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HISTSIZE=1000
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LOGNAME=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
OLDPWD=/var/log/puppetlabs
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin
PWD=/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
TERM=xterm
USER=root
[root@localhost puppetserver]#
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the output of `env | sort` ?

Comment: @SHW updated same at above post , please check.

Comment: Check the date after `export TZ='Asia/Kolkata` command

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's causing your timezone not to change, but you can try changing it manually to see if the changes are saved in manual method.

Run the following commands:

```
rm /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime
date 013122172017
hwclock --systohc
```

Date format:  `MMDDhhmmYYYY`

Let me know if the changes are saved and take effect.